# angular JS $rootScope undefined inside $http.get

Tags: angularjs, undefined

I want to retrieve data from an $http.get and put it in $rootScope :

**.run**

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $q, $http, $timeout, stateRules) {

    stateRules
    .then(function (data) {
        $rootScope.user = data;
        console.log(data);
    });   
});
```

**.service**

```
 app.service('stateRules', ['$http','$q', function($http, $q) {
    var userUrl= 'api/user/';
    var userService = {};
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(userUrl+ "getUserName", { cache: true }).success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

.controller

```
app.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', function ( $scope) {
        console.log($scope.user);

}]);
```

but the value of the $scope.user in my controller is undefined. Any idea how to fix it ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you inject it to your controller?

Comment: Yes. When i use $rootScope.user = "test" , in my controller the $scope.user shows test. When i use $rootScope.user inside the $http.get,  $scope.user show undefined. Note that when i do console.log(data) in the $http.get, i see the data

Comment: Are you using a mangling-system like uglifyjs?


post how do you declare the variable app...

Comment: i use $window.sessionStorage.currentUser. Less trouble !

Answer (score 0):

$rootScope should be injected in a service. like this.

`.service('ServiceGetSVC', ['$http','$rootScope','$q',function ($http,$rootScope,$q) {....}`

Or if you try to use $rootScope.user after method get. It was undefined becouse method get asynchronous.  Should use deferred.

in application

```
ServiceGetSVC.then(data){
  $rootScope.user = data;
}

service 
  .service('stateRules', ['$http','$q' function($http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(communUrl + "getUserName", { cache: true }).success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }])
```

Comment: The goal is to have the $rootScope.user in my app.run so i can use the user value in all my controllers. It's not a problem with the Injector but with the $http.get

Comment: I add simple solution.

Comment: Same problem ! i still have undefined. I updated my initial question with more code.

Comment: i use $window.sessionStorage. Less trouble !